# Showing that a contour integral goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to show that $\int_{-b}^{b} \frac{f(N+\frac{1}{2} + it)}{e^{2\pi i(N+\frac{1}{2} + it)}-1} dt \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ where $|f(N+1/2+it)| \le A/(1+(N+1/2)^2)$ for some constant $A$.

To show this, I have $|\int_{-b}^{b} \frac{f(N+\frac{1}{2} + it)}{e^{2\pi i(N+\frac{1}{2} + it)}-1} dt |\le \frac{A}{1+N^2} \int_{-b}^b \frac{1}{|e^{2\pi i(N+\frac{1}{2})} e^{-2\pi t} - 1|} dt \le \frac{A}{1+N^2} \int_{-b}^b \frac{dt}{e^{-2 \pi t} - 1}.$

My proof would be complete if we have $\int_{-b}^b \frac{dt}{e^{-2 \pi t} - 1}$ exists. However, I don't know think it does. How can I  show that the contour integral vanishes in the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The integrand is a continuous function that never equals $0$ on the interval of integration.

Comment: I made a critical mistake in the question, the $-1$ should be outside of the exponential

Comment: What do you now mean by the "integral exists"?

Comment: If the integral were finite I would have the original contour integral vanish as $N \to \infty$. But I can see it isn’t finite. How can I still show that the contour integral vanishes in the limit?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int_{-b}^b\frac{dt}{e^{-2\pi t-1}}=\int_{-b}^be^{2\pi t+1}\,dt=e\int_{-b}^b(e^{\pi t})^2\,dt=2e\int_0^b(e^{\pi t})^2\,dt.$$

Given $\forall t\in\Bbb R, e^{\pi t}>0$, the integral converges.

---

Edit:
We have $$\int_{-b}^b\frac{dt}{e^{-2\pi t}-1}=\int_{-b}^b\frac{e^{2\pi t}}{1-e^{2\pi t}}\,dt=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-b}^b\frac1u\,du$$
for which you can take Cauchy and set to be $0$, or declare as divergent.

Comment: I made a critical mistake in the question, the $-1$ should be outside of the exponential.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I have made an edit; please take a look.

Comment: Yes I have just realized this integral doesn’t exist. My main question was how to show that the contour integral vanishes in the limit if $f$ is of moderate decrease in the real line. How can I deal with the exponential part in the denominator?